# Perform grouping by order and value

Tags: r

I need to assign group to events going in a row. 
I'll explain by example:

```
events <- c('b', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'd', 'd', 'd')
```

And I want to produce this result (group letters going in a row):

```
group <-  c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5)
```

The obvious solution for me is this:

```
1 + cumsum(apply(cbind(c = events, n = c(NA_character_, rev(rev(events)[-1]))), 1, function(x) !is.na(x["n"]) && x["c"] != x["n"]))
```

Is there more beautiful way of doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use factors. If you don't really care for the order of the levels, just do:

```
factor(events)
```

This should be enough for most situations, although I don't know exactly what you plan to do next.

If you care for the order, do

```
factor(events, levels = unique(events))
```

If you want to drop the levels and only keep the integer representation:

```
as.integer(factor(events, levels = unique(events)))
#  [1]  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  4  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 16 17 18
# [28] 18 19 20 21 22 22
```

Another short solution:

```
match(events, unique(events))
```

**Edit**: assuming levels can appear in more than one contiguous subsets and if you want to differentiate these with a new value (c.f. your edit) you could do:

```
cumsum(c(TRUE, head(events, -1) != tail(events, -1)))
```

or

```
inverse.rle(within.list(rle(events), values <- seq_along(values)))
```

Comment: Ups.. I should edit question. Sorry - your solution is perfect if and only if event are unique.